# How to copy from a file opened in vim on linux server to my windows notepad ++

Tags: vim

I tried "* and "+ , but none work. 
Can someone please suggest the best way to copy all lines from vim to my notepad++ .

I am still new to vim and still learning

```
$ vim -version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 20 2016 17:29:42)
Garbage after option argument: "-version"
More info with: "vim -h"
```

Comment: How are you accessing Linux server and Windows (RDP, ssh, VNC)? Which is your host OS?

Comment: The post, https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim, is very similar to yours and provides specific direction for SSH.

Comment: 4.1.12-124.16.4.el6uek.x86_64

Comment: ]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu How do i know if "*yy or "*p work or not , i press , but nothing works.

Comment: The echo test for +clipboard returns 0...does it mean it wont work with my vim version ? :( ..i cannot install any software on these linux servers as we dont have privileges

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu i am using putty/Mobaxterm for accessing LInux server from my windows laptop. via ssh . My host is windows 10

Comment: Are you unable to use scp or rsync? Those would be so much easier... In any case, I believe in your setting vim does not have access to your Windows clipboard, only putty would, so the mouse can capture what's on screen and on the scrollback buffer, but not directly what's in vim.

Comment: @joanisYes i can use scp , but sometimes i just want to copy few lines from vim when i am doing the development and i would like to use vim in order to do that. That is why i posted this question ,so that i can somehow find a hack to work with :)

Comment: Hi , Can anyone suggest any other hacks :) ?

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1: Copy the full file*: There is a drag and drop option in Mobaxterm which you can use for copying files.

*Option 2: Copy part of the file (mentioned by @Sach in the comments)*:

- Copy the part of the file (using Vim) which you want to copy using the start and end line numbers. `:<starting_line_number>,<ending_line_number>w filename`. [Credits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/vi-vim-how-can-i-write-out-a-number-of-lines-to-a-new-file)
- Copy the new file to Windows using *option 1*.